# Correct multiple polynomial regression formula with OLS in Python

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I need to perform multiple polynomial regression and obtain statistics, p value, AIC etc.
As far as I understood I can do that with OLS, however I found only a way to produce a formula using one independent variable, like this:

```
model = 'act_hours ~ h_hours + I(h_hours**2)'
hours_model = smf.ols(formula = model, data = df)
```

I tried to define a formula using two independent variable, however I could not understand if that is the correct way and if the results are reasonable. The line that I doubt is `model = 'Height ~ Diamet + I(Diamet**2) + area + I(area**2)`. The full code is this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

train = pd.read_csv(r'W:\...file.csv')

model = 'Height ~ Diamet + I(Diamet**2) + area + I(area**2)'
hours_model = smf.ols(formula = model, data = train).fit()
print(hours_model.summary())
```

The summary of the regression is here:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 Height   R-squared:                       0.611
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.609
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     376.0
Date:                Fri, 04 Feb 2022   Prob (F-statistic):          1.33e-194
Time:                        08:50:17   Log-Likelihood:                -5114.6
No. Observations:                 963   AIC:                         1.024e+04
Df Residuals:                     958   BIC:                         1.026e+04
Df Model:                           4                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==================================================================================
                     coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept         13.9287     60.951      0.229      0.819    -105.684     133.542
Diamet             0.6027      0.340      1.770      0.077      -0.066       1.271
I(Diamet ** 2)     0.0004      0.002      0.262      0.794      -0.003       0.004
area                3.3553      5.307      0.632      0.527      -7.060      13.771
I(area** 2)        0.2519      0.108      2.324      0.020       0.039       0.465
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       60.996   Durbin-Watson:                   1.889
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               86.039
Skew:                           0.528   Prob(JB):                     2.07e-19
Kurtosis:                       4.015   Cond. No.                     4.45e+05
==============================================================================
Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The condition number is large, 4.45e+05. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.
```

Comment: Have you looked into Scikit learn? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: The expression is correct but the independent variables are correlated, no? That’s part of the reason why it has no explanatory power. Especially if the data points are circles, then diameter and area have one-to-one relationship.